# HDMI connection from a Sony Vaio VGN-2950 to external display does not work (but VGA does)

Tags: hdmi, external-display

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-2950 with a HDMI connection and a Samsung 24A350H external monitor with an HDMI input.

If I connect the laptop to the Samsung via a VGA connection, it works fine. However, it won’t work when using HDMI; the screen stays blank.

Any ideas how I can get it to work with HDMI?

Comment: Are you sure the cable's good?

Comment: Resolution needs to be "good" maybe?

Answer (score -1):

As long as you have your display drivers installed properly, you should see the option "Output To ->" when you right click on your desktop and look under display or properties. If HDMI is connected, You should see the option Output To - TV.

Comment: This answer is technically correct... but only valid on some versions of Windows. And not likely to solve the problem given the details provided.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I also have a Sony Vaio laptop and a TV connected using HDMI, it used to work fine, but one day it did not. The VGA cable still worked fine.

Here is my solution:

- Reboot PC.
- Go to BIOS, by pressing F2 or whichever key is correct for your computer.
- Within the BIOS settings, disable Intel Visualization Technology.
- Reboot computer.

And it should work. If there is no such option, go to BIOS and restore the original BIOS settings from the BIOS menu.

Comment: I think you mean Intel Virtualization Technology... which has *nothing* to do with display output. There is no such thing as Intel Visualization Technology.

Answer (score -2):

You might need to check whether your graphic card driver `services` are working or not, having them disabled might not detect connection to external device.

Comment: Just for those who down voted, I had similar issue with HDMI not working from my laptop to my TV, for some reason NVIDIA GPU driver service was not started, when I started it, the TV showed the output!